# How to validate email by whitelist domain regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate domain by whitelist such as : .com , .co.id, .org,

here i have a regex pattern :

`/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*(\+[a-z0-9-]+)?@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*$/i;`

so if the user input :

- example@example.gov -> **invalid**
- example@example.com -> **valid**

anyone can help me out ? 
Thank you

Comment: `@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)$/i;` fiddle this part with something like `@[a-z0-9-]+\.[com|...|other-tld]` you can fiddle on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) it also had helpful guide on the lower right.

Comment: Do you have a list of domains that you want to check inside the regex (e.g. `[com|org]`), or do you want to extract the domain with the regex and then compare it some other way?

Comment: solved, thank you guys ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed in two steps:

- Check that the email is well formed -> example: https://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html, there are many sources on this subject
- Validate that the domain is in the whitelist of domains

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
   
    //check that the input string is an well formed email 
    var emailFilter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!emailFilter.test(email)) {
        return false;
    }

    //check that the input email is in the whitelist
    var s, domainWhitelist = [".com", "co.id", ".org"];
    for (s of domainWhitelist)
      if(email.endsWith(s))
        return true;
    
    //if we reach this point it means that the email is well formed but not in the whitelist
    return false;
}

console.log("validate ->" + validateEmail(""));
console.log("validate abc ->" + validateEmail("abc"));
console.log("validate example@example.gov ->" + validateEmail("example@example.gov"));
console.log("validate example@example.com ->" + validateEmail("example@example.com"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
let e = ["example@example.gov",
         "example@example.com",
         "example@example.co.id",
         "example@example.org"];

let d = [".com", ".co.id", ".org"];

let f = x=> d.some(y => new RegExp(`@.*?(${y})`).test(x));

let v = e.filter(x=> f(x));

console.log(v);     // show valid emails
```

**Explanation**: of regexp: It match the letters after first dot after `@`. First we get any characters after @ in non-greedy way by `.*?` then we open group `(` before first dot `\.` and check that all left characters are domain `${y})`.

Comment: how if not in array ?

Comment: @NotaPwntester I update answer - use function `f('email')` and you will get `true/false`